# Javascript backbutton event listener overrides the android device back button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, back-button

I have created `Android app` using `cordova 2.6.0`. I have implemented a `menu` feature in my app using `html` markups and `jQuery` which toggles on interacting with device's `menubutton`. But I could not figure out to achieve the following requirement, to behave like a native app.

**Requirement**

The `menu` should hide on pressing device's `backbutton` if the `menu` is `visible`. If the `menu` is not visible the `backbutton` should now act normally, which is, either it should `exit` the `app` or go to the `back history`.

**This is my code**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

document.addEventListener('menubutton', function(){
//Toggle Menu
//Which is working fine
});

document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
if(menu is visible) {
  //Hide the menu
  //This is also working fine
return false;
} 

//BUT the default action of backbutton has gone. It cannot exit the app , neither it brings to back history.

//return true;
//I have also tried to return boolean true , but facing the same problem.
});

}, false);
```

**The actual problem**

If I attached an `eventlistener` for `backbutton` the device's `Back Button` is disabled, It does not works as normal.

**My question is**

Is `document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){});` over riding the device's back button? How to get rid of it?

**This is happening on Android 4.1.2 Device**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have overridden the back button using the listener, it doesn't perform the native functionalities. You have to implement the exit behaviour as well.

In your overriding method, use the following

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){
  if(menu is visible) {
       //Hide the menu
       //This is also working fine
   return false;
  }
  else //nothing is visible, exit the app
  {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I change something in `java` or it is completely `impossible`?

Comment: I'm not aware of the exact possibility in java, but that's the basic rule of programming, once you have overridden you need to implement the complete functionality in your own function.

Comment: If I need to do It manually, How could i `exit` the app if there is nothing in `history` and go to `back history` if there is one? please help!

Comment: Even if you do not implement the back button listener, the back button history needs to be maintained by you only. As there exists only one activity you'll always exit on pressing the back button. You need to maintain the history yourself. Example:On moving to another pages/views, keep adding the paths to a global array and pop elements on pressing the back button

Comment: You can also navigate back using `history.go(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> Is document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(){}); over riding the device's back button? How to get rid of it?

You can as well remove the event listener on page redirect to continue using the native functionality of back button in subsequent pages. Code to remove event listener as follows:

`document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);` where onBackButton is the function associated with the back button event.